# Git merge branches, master into develop

Tags: git, version-control, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a develop branch and a master branch in Git for the same project.

The develop branch has different deployment code to master.

I had a set of changes to make for a client so made them to master as they wanted it live quickly.

Now the master branch does not contain these changes.

I am wanting to know if i have to make these changes back to the develop branch manually or if there is a way (or safe) to merge master back into develop branch so both are up to date with the latest changes?

Thanks

Comment: You mean "Now the _development_ branch does not contain these changes."  instead of "Now the master branch ...", right?

Comment: Yes, you can merge master to development, you can always merge. If it is the correct thing to do depends on what you want to achieve exactly. I'd say, your current question is too broad.

Comment: Have you get the answer which helps you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also 

benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way would probably be to cherry pick the commits with these changes off the one branch onto the other.  This would ensure that only the changes you intend get on to the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebase your develop branch onto master branch, in case you have any merge conflicts (if you have changed the same lines of codes differently in both the branches), you should solve the conflicts and then just git add the changes and continue the rebase.

```
 git checkout develop
 git rebase master

--- solve the conflicts if there are any, after solving it, ---

git add .
git rebase --continue (until the conflicts are solved)
```

Another way is to use git cherry-pick the commits from master branch to develop branch. You might need to solve merge conflicts in this method as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following [IF `develop` is the branch which is messed up and has to be made same as `master`],

```
git checkout develop
git reset --hard origin master  # DISCLAIMER: This will remove all your changes in develop
git fetch origin master
```

Now your `develop` is exactly like `master`.

However, if you still want to keep the changes in `develop` but want the things that are there in the `master` too, do the following,

```
git checkout develop
git rebase master  # Might have to fix some conflicts here
```

and you're done.